# Flutter autofill hints not showing dropdown suggestions for TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, autofill

I have a signup form with email, password, first name, and last name, and I want to take advantage of Google Autofill to auto fill these fields. I'm trying to use `autofillHints:[AutofillHints.email]` in my TextFormFields for example, but when I tap into the email field, the autofill dropdown suggestions do not appear. Instead they appear as keyboard hints, but even when I tap on the keyboard hint, nothing happens.

[image]

I want the hints to show up as a dropdown suggestion menu like so:
[image]

Here's an example of my code for one of my fields:

```
TextFormField(
          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
          enableSuggestions: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          focusNode: _emailFocus,
          onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
            _emailFocus.unfocus();
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocus);
          },
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: bodyFont, color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: igBlack),),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: bodyFont,fontSize: 16, color: igBlack),
          cursorColor: Colors.red,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter some text';
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (email) {
            setState(
              () {
                this.email = email;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Does this happen in a web build or Android / iOS? Do you have an `AutoFillGroup` above your `TextFormField` widgets?

Comment: Hi @PeterKoltai this happens when I debug the app in my Android phone (Pixel 4a). I do not have an AutoFillGroup. Should I have that on the outside of all my textformfields?

Comment: Yes, you need an `AutofillGroup`, check it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutofillGroup-class.html).

Comment: And I also think it won't work on emulator, only on real device.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I am debugging it on a real device, on my phone using USB debugging. Wrapping it in AutofillGroup didn't work :/

Comment: @PeterKoltai Nevermind, I think your suggestion did fix it. The pixel must not have a dropdown menu option for apps. It's working now when I tap the keyword hint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `TextFormField` with autofillHints configured with [AutofillGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutofillGroup-class.html) to help display text field hints.